# XPath / C# not returning what's expected

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

This is the HTML I'm trying to parse. I want to get each individual td inner text.

```
<tbody>
    <tr class="past">
        <!--<th><span class="place">Lugar</span></th>-->
        <td class="date">14/02/2012</td>
        <td class="hour">16:25</td>
        <td class="status">Entregue</td>
    </tr>   
    <tr class="past">
        <!--<th><span class="place">Lugar</span></th>-->
        <td class="date">13/02/2012</td>
        <td class="hour">16:59</td>
        <td class="status">Destinat&aacute;rio ausente ou fechado</td>
    </tr>   
    <tr class="past">
        <!--<th><span class="place">Lugar</span></th>-->
        <td class="date">11/02/2012</td>
        <td class="hour">14:09</td>
        <td class="status">Envio recolhido na origem</td>
    </tr>   
    <tr class="past">
        <!--<th><span class="place">Lugar</span></th>-->
        <td class="date">-</td>
        <td class="hour">-</td>
        <td class="status">Pendente de entrega &agrave; MRW</td>
    </tr>   
</tbody>
```

I'm using this piece of code to run throught every td on this table:

```
foreach (HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tbody/tr/td"))
{
    Console.WriteLine("TD: " + link.InnerText);
}
```

This foreach only prints once and it's the entire table. I've searched everywhere on Google and the XPath expression should be right. Can you figure out what the problem is?

Comment: Where have you found those HtmlNode and DocumentNode classes? I can't find them in MSDN. ¿Why don't you use XmlNode?

Comment: It's from the HtmlAgilityPack on codeplex, I've used it before for parsing Html and it's considered the best :\ It's just this time, I can't figure out what's wrong. I'll try with XmlNode.

Comment: Your XPath is correct. You should check HtmlAgilityPack docs, and see what exactly does SelectNodes. By the way, any XML library, including .NET libraries are not tolerant with malformed docs. This can create some trouble. According to docs HtmlAgilityPack is tolerant to malformed documents. So, depending on the origin of your HTML docs you should stuck with HtmlAgilityPack.

Comment: "This project does not have documentation yet." I'll check with the method suggestion tooltip on Visual Studio. Does XmlNode also work with Html files or just Xml files?

Comment: html files are kinda xml files

Comment: Look in the downloads section of HtmlAgilityPack. There you have the docs.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct. If you try to parse only given piece of code, program will output this:

```
TD: 14/02/2012
TD: 16:25
TD: Entregue
TD: 13/02/2012
TD: 16:59
TD: Destinatário ausente ou fechado
TD: 11/02/2012
TD: 14:09
TD: Envio recolhido na origem
TD: -
TD: -
TD: Pendente de entrega à MRW
```

I assume this is what you want. Problem is in your original document. Try to open document in some other software tool that will display you complete DOM tree and you will see. Problably you will have to modify your XPath expression.